# Zsh: remove # - comment when pasting to terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminal, zsh

I use clipmenu to choose something to paste into terminal that running zsh as shell.

Problem is that zsh will echo error when for example I paste a shell function that contains some # for comments inside that function. I have to manually go back and clear all lines contain #.

System: archlinux/zsh/clipmenu

EDIT: example of function:

```
test() {
    # must remove this line manually after paste into zsh's shell
    <do something>
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of such a function?

Comment: @Kusalananda: Thanks, I've just added one.

Comment: It might help future searchers if you included the zsh error, presumably `zsh: command not found: #`

Comment: @JeffSchaller, the error would only be upon running the function (though in the specific OP's example, there's also a problem with the unmatched single quote), and you'd get a _command not found_ or _bad pattern_ depending on whether the `extendedglob` option is set or not.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/557486/5132 for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you just need to `setopt interactivecomments`?