# Allowing comments in interactive zsh commands

Tags: zsh, command-history

It might be useful to allow comments in `zsh` commands written on the command line, as
in `bash`, but

```
% echo test # test
zsh: bad pattern: #
```

Any way to get the same behaviour as in the `bash` shell?

Comment: You can add # comments at the end of line and they're written in history (at least in Bash). What do you mean by multiline?

Comment: @Tomasz Zsh history file format has support for multiline commands as a single history item. As in, you press <up>, and a set of lines may be returned to the prompt. It's useful for loops and pipes written across multiple lines. Toothrot probably wants comments in lines prior to code.

Answer (score 43):

```bash
$ setopt interactive_comments
$ echo hello # comment
hello
```

By default, the `zsh` shell enables the `interactive_comments` shell option in scripts (non-interactive shells in general), but not when running an interactive session.

The relevant bit from the `zsh` manual:

> COMMENTS
> In non-interactive shells, or in interactive shells with the
> `INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS` option set, a word beginning with the third
> character of the histchars parameter (`#` by default) causes that word
> and all the following characters up to a newline to be ignored.

Without this shell option set, you'd only get the `bad pattern` error if the `extended_glob` shell option is set.  With `extended_glob` set, `x#` would match zero or more of the pattern `x` and `x##` would match one or more of the pattern `x` (these correspond to the regular expression modifiers `*` and `+`).  This means that with `extended_glob` set and `interactive_comments` *unset*, the shell is complaining about the syntax used in an extended filename globbing pattern modifier you used unknowingly.

---

The values in `histchars` are by default `!^#`, and the first two characters are used in history expansions.

Since comments in `zsh` are delimited by `$histchars[3]`, changing this character will change what text is considered to be a comment:

```bash
$ setopt extended_glob
$ echo hello # hello : hello
zsh: bad pattern: #
```

```bash
$ unsetopt extended_glob
$ echo hello # hello : hello
hello # hello : hello
```

```bash
$ setopt interactive_comments
$ echo hello # hello : hello
hello
```

```bash
$ histchars[3]=:
$ echo hello # hello : hello
hello # hello
```

---

Interestingly (?), the `bash` shell also has an `interactive_comments` shell option, but this is turned on by default in interactive shells:

```bash
$ echo hello # hello
hello
```

```bash
$ shopt -u interactive_comments
$ echo hello # hello
hello # hello
```

Comment: thanks!  any idea why this is not on by default?

Comment: I suspect it’s not on by default because it would break backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Toothrot What Stephen just said, also there is very seldom any use for comments in interactive shells.

Comment: @Toothrot I've added a bit about what `#` is used for when it's not a comment.

Comment: @StephenKitt sorry if I'm mistaken, but isn't backward compatibility a non-issue for interactive shells since they are operated by a human by definition, and there is no legacy code, save for stuff that is copy-pasted?

Comment: @Clashsoft I'm not entirely certain, but I think Stephen _might_ refer to older versions of the `zsh` shell (i.e. backward compatibility to older versions). This shell has been around since 1990.

Comment: @Clashsoft technically it is indeed a non-issue, but you’ve have to re-wire a few humans... Perhaps a more accurate way to present it would be “principle of least surprise”. My history shows quite a few `#` (typically in commit messages with bug numbers), I for one would be thrown a little if `interactive_comments` became the default in interactive shells.

Comment: I need this on because I tend work work with a lot of documentation that has explanations on the same line in a comment and I prefer to be able to copy/paste the command(s) as a whole as they appear.

Comment: @StephenKitt, So far as I can tell, the # symbol can still be used inside "quotes", even when `interactive_comments` is enabled. So, unless your git commit messages are just a single unquoted issue number, I think they would still work.

Comment: @daviewales yes, of course; this was for `-m #1234`-style portions of commit messages. Nowadays I use prefixes so the hash symbols always end up quoted.

Comment: That's another csh heritage. csh is where `# comments` come from (but weren't recognised when interactive) and the shell that was popular at the time zsh was written. bash initially behaves like csh/zsh, though in later versions, you could tweak the default at build time with a `INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS` in config.h which became the default for POSIX compliant. In 2.0, that become a runtime option enabled by default.

Comment: Actually, in zsh 1.0 (1990) there was the same `INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS` C macro,  not enabled by default. Became a runtime option in 2.0 in 1991.