# "Command not found: #" in sourced multiline command with comments

Tags: zsh

In *foo.sh*, I have some commands (or functions) split to multiple lines and added comments, for readability:

```
#!/bin/zsh
#
# foo.sh: print computer information

foo() {
    uname \
        -p `# processor arch` \
        -s `# os name` \
        -v `# os version`
}

foo
```

---

###### What works

I can run it okay:

```
$ ./foo.sh
Darwin 123... (correct output)
```

---

###### What doesn't work

But if I source it with `source` or `.`, my shell reports the following error, although the command it self is successfully run with my specified arguments (`-psv`):

```
% . ./foo.sh
./foo.sh:2: command not found: #
./foo.sh:2: command not found: #
./foo.sh:2: command not found: #
Darwin 123... (correct output as before)
```

I wonder why this happens? And how do I fix it? Because my primary goal is to define some functions, source them, and call them in shell as I need. Thank you!

Comment: What is `-p #` supposed to do? Is this supposed to be a comment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allowing comments in interactive zsh commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557486/allowing-comments-in-interactive-zsh-commands)

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk on the line `-p \`# processor arch\` \\`, `-p` is the argument, the "`\`# processor arch\``" quoted is comment, and "`\`" is multiline separator.

Comment: Is `\`# ... \`` some kind of zsh extension?  In normal shell syntax that would be a command substitution (of a somewhat nonsensical command).

Comment: @zwol It's regular POSIX code. OP's intent seems to be to add comments in between line continuations. Since this isn't directly supported, they're using this "hack" by including command substitutions that expand to nothing.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I _see_.

Comment: Store the options in an array, which allows you to mix comments and elements in the assignment.

Comment: Why do you call your script "*.sh" and then run it with zsh? That leads to this kind of confusion -- call it "*.zsh" or use Bourne shell syntax inside the script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, zsh only recognizes comments in scripts, not when running interactively. This should apply to sourced scripts, but in recent versions (I've reproduced this behavior in 5.8, but 5.4.2 accepts your code just fine), this also applies to some code that is parsed after loading, such as code inside command substitution. This is probably a bug.

Put [`setopt interactive_comments`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-INTERACTIVE_005fCOMMENTS) in your `.zshrc` to support comments when running interactively. This doesn't really have a downside: it means you have to quote `#` at the beginning of a word, but `#` rarely appears at the beginning of a word on a command line. (`#` within a word doesn't start a comment, so this doesn't affect the use of `#` as an `extended_glob` wildcard character or in parameter expansion.)

Alternatively (or in addition), add

```
setopt local_options interactive_comments
```

inside the function. Then the comments will work.

Comment: Thank you, Gilles. The most helpful part of your answer, in addition to explaining how `#` is interpreted in zsh, is that you directly pointed out the option to set `local_options` inside the function. Because I haven't worked with `setopt` before at all, it will take me much time to figure out how to set the option to affect this function only.

Comment: A follow up is, inside the function, without setting `interactive_comments`, something like `pwd # 123` will work, which won't with `$ pwd # 123`. How is this different from comments in the multiline command?

Comment: That's not (fully) correct. Comments are recognised in files sourced from interactive shells. If not, you wouldn't be able to source any script or your ~/.zshrc. Here, it looks more like a bug.

Comment: I also doubt `setopt local_options interactive_comments` inside a function would work as that affects the parsing and functions are parsed before they're run (including that `setopt` command).

Comment: Actually a regression. It was fine in zsh 4.0.1

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Indeed this appears to be a bug. Works fine in zsh 5.4.2, breaks in command substitutions in 5.8.2.

Comment: See also https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2021/msg01561.html, comments used to be recognised inside command substitutions, even in interactive shells with interactivecomments off. They still are inside process substitution.