# Comments are causing errors after changing the value of "histchars" in zsh

Tags: zsh, syntax

Why, after using `set histchars='?'`, is there an error that occurs every time I source `~/.zshrc`?

```
/home/user/.zshrc:1: bad pattern: #
```

In other words, every `#` token within comments is causing some issues.

Comment: Please update your question and include 1) the line from your `.zshrc` file that caused the issue, 2) the output from `setopt`, and 3) the command you ran (the one you show would cause an error).  I would _expect_ that error to occur if you paste code containing comments into an interactive `zsh` shell.  That is the default behaviour of `zsh` (see e.g. [Allowing comments in interactive zsh commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/557486)). Sourcing a script should still work, and changing the `histchars` variable to a single `?` should give you a `command not found` error instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda Assuming the code is actually `histchars='?'` without `set` or `setopt`, your (currently deleted) answer is correct.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' It would generate a "command not found" error, not a "bad pattern" error, though. It's unclear what this user is actually doing.  I closed the question as they had had time to ask a new question without caring for clarifying this one.

Comment: @Kusalananda It would be a bad pattern error if `setopt extended_glob` is also present, which is very likely.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thanks. I'll double-check and update my answer. I will keep the question closed as it's still unclear what the user actually did. EDIT: I'm reopening the question to allow you to post your own answer alongside min if you wish to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The command that you show ought to give you the following error message:

```
setopt: no such option: histchars=?
```

It should have no other effect.

However, if you set the `histchars` variable to the single character `?`, then you disable the use of comments in the shell.  This is because the `zsh` shell uses the *third* character of the `histchars` variable as the comment indicator.

The variable is documented like this in the `zshparam(1)` manual:

> Three characters used by the shell's history and lexical
> analysis mechanism.  The first character signals the start of a
> history expansion (default `!`).  The second character signals
> the start of a quick history substitution (default `^`).  The
> third character is the comment character (default `#`).
>
> The characters must be in the ASCII character set; any attempt
> to set `histchars` to characters with a locale-dependent meaning
> will be rejected with an error message.

Setting `histshars=?` would provoke a `command not found` error for each comment character where a command is usually allowed (like at the start of a line).  If you have set the `EXTENDED_GLOB` shell option in the shell, a `bad pattern` error would be generated instead.

If you want to change the initial character of `histchars`,
the history expansion indicator, to a question mark, use

```bash
histchars[1]=?
```