# why does ZSH pass # and arguments following to process?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, process

I did some experimenting and:

```
alex.mills@alex wss % node /Users/alex.mills/codes/vibeirl/wss/scripts/arg-test.js -v a # 3
[
  '/Users/alex.mills/.nodenv/versions/14.17.0/bin/node',
  '/Users/alex.mills/codes/vibeirl/wss/scripts/arg-test.js',
  '-v',
  'a',
  '#',
  '3'
]
alex.mills@alex wss % echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
alex.mills@alex wss % bash

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
%n@%m %1~ %# node /Users/alex.mills/codes/vibeirl/wss/scripts/arg-test.js -v a # 3
[
  '/Users/alex.mills/.nodenv/versions/14.17.0/bin/node',
  '/Users/alex.mills/codes/vibeirl/wss/scripts/arg-test.js',
  '-v',
  'a'
]
%n@%m %1~ %#
```

in my node app, I just have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log(process.argv);
```

anyone know why ZSH elects to pass the # and any arguments following to the process but Bash does not?

Comment: See [Allowing comments in interactive zsh commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557486/allowing-comments-in-interactive-zsh-commands)